# Rotate div whitouth breaking structure

Tags: css

I'm trying to keep the rotated block to align on top of remaining blocks in the right side of the window.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8tbL6rqs/1/

```
<div class="side">
    <div class="block-first">Chat with us</div>
    <div class="block">Phone</div>
    <div class="block">Mail</div>  
<div>

.side {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:30%;
}

.block, .block-first {
    background: #f00;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}

.block-first {
    width:200px!important;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: Try `transform-origin`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to `.block-first`:

```
position:relative;
top:-75px;
left:-75px;
```

Here's an updated **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tbL6rqs/2/)**.